# Preencher JComboBox com um objeto

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Gostaria de uma ajuda para preencher um [`JComboBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html)  com uma classe. Nesta classe, retorno dois parâmetros: Id e Desc.

Classe categoria que preciso mostrar no combo:

```
private int Id_categoria;
private String Desc_Categoria;
```

Como faço para mostrar apenas a `Desc_categoria`? E na hora de selecionar algum valor, como pego só o `Id_Categoria`?

Já tentei, passar como parâmetro no [`JComboBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) um array do tipo categoria e também adicionar um model.

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Adicione na pergunta.

Comment: Como você obtém esses valores? Você quer exibir apenas um valor ou vários?

Comment: Recebo os valores do banco e crio um arrayList de categorias, gostaria de exibir esta lista

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma outra solução seria utilizar o [comboModel](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JComboBoxUsingtheCustomModel.htm). Exemplo simples:

```
public class AulaComboModel extends AbstractListModel<Aula> implements ComboBoxModel<Aula> {

    private List<Aula> lista;

    /* Seleciona um objeto na caixa de seleção */
    private Aula selecionado;

    /* Método construtor */
    public AulaComboModel() {
        /* Popula a lista */
        popular();

        /* Define o objeto selecionado */
        setSelectedItem(lista.get(0));
    }

    /* Captura o tamanho da listagem */
    public int getSize() {
        int totalElementos = lista.size();
        return totalElementos;
    }

    /* Captura um elemento da lista em uma posição informada */
    public Aula getElementAt(int indice) {
        Aula t = lista.get(indice);
        return t;
    }

    /* Marca um objeto na lista como selecionado */
    public void setSelectedItem(Object item) {
        selecionado = (Aula) item;
    }

    /* Captura o objeto selecionado da lista */
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        return selecionado;
    }

    private void popular() {
        try {
            /* Cria o DAO */
            AulaDAO tdao = new AulaDAO();

            /* Cria um modelo vazio */
            Aula t = new Aula();
            t.setNomeUsuario("");

            /* Recupera os registros da tabela */
            lista = tdao.buscar(t);

            /* Cria o primeiro registro da lista */
            Aula primeiro = new Aula();
            primeiro.setIdUsuario(0);
            primeiro.setNomeUsuario("--SELECIONE UM USUARIO--");

            /* Adiciona o primeiro registro a lista */
            lista.add(0, primeiro);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Nesse `comboModel` eu recupero os registros do banco da seguinte forma:  `lista = tdao.buscar(t);`

Para implementar esse comboModel é necessário sobrescrever o método `equals` e o `toString`

Faça isso no model, exemplo:

```
 @Override
 public String toString() {
        String texto = idUsuario+" - "+ nomeUsuario;
        return texto;
    }

  @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       Aula f = (Aula) obj;
       return Objects.equals(this.idUsuario, f.idUsuario);
   }
```

Repare que no `toString` eu estou concatenando o id e o nome.

Se estiver usando netBeans vá no componente comboModel, clique com o botão direito e vá para **propriedades > model > código personalizado** e então instancie o modelo criado: `new AulaComboModel()`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa seria uma solução um pouco "maior" para seu problema, mas o uso do `comboModel` pode facilitar e deixar seu código mais organizado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas a classe responsável pela exibição do JCombobox não é a DefaulListCellRenderer?

Comment: Sim, mas o modelo (preenchimento) pode ser feito pelo `AbstractListModel`

Comment: Ah ta, nem sabia. Sempre crio um model e um renderer separados mesmo.

Comment: Eu fazia dessa forma também, então um amigo me ensinou a fazer dessa forma. Na documentação tem uns exemplos também. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Answer (score 5):

### **Solução 1**

Na sua custom class, adicione o método `toString()` de forma a retornar o parametro `Desc_Categoria`:

```
@Override
public String toString()
    return this.Desc_Categoria;
}
```

### Solução 2

Você pode personalizar a exibição do `Jcombobox` através do método `getListCellRendererComponent`, da classe [DefaultListCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html):

```
DefaultListCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                  if (value instanceof SuaCustomClasse) {
                    SuaCustomClasse minhaclasse = (SuaCustomClasse) value;
                    setText(minhaclasse.getDesc_Categoria);//supondo que seu parametro seja encapsulado
                }
                return this;
            }

...

   combo.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Desta forma, você está alterando como o `JCombobox` exibe os elementos adicionados a ele. Dá para criar uma `ListCellRenderer` customizada também, mas depende da necessidade e da complexidade dos objetos que serão adicionados no seu combobox.