# Preencher um jCombobox usando join e hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, jcombobox

Estou fazendo um trabalho na faculdade que onde devo criar um sistema de agenda para vendedores de uma concessionaria  de veiculos. As tecnologias utilizadas são Java, Swing, e Hibernate.

Dividi o projeto em camadas para facilitar, criei as classes cliente, vendedor e compromisso para agendar as atividades dos vendedores com os clientes. Para cada uma dessas classes estão na camada domain, a conexão os métodos de salvar, pesquisar excluir estão na camada dao, e existe uma camada chamada control que chama os metodos de uma interface de cada classe DAO.

Fiz a tela de cliente, fiz a tela de Vendedores, mas na tela de Compromisso tem um `JComboBox` que era para mostrar os vendedores e outro para monstrar os clientes , mas só aparece as referencias deles e não os nomes.

Como faço para aparecer o nomes dos vendedores e clientes?

[Projeto no BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/jmfrolim/agendacase/src)

**Segue código do control compromisso:**

```
package control;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import model.dao.CompromissoDao;
import model.dao.CompromissoDaoImp;
import model.domain.Cliente;
import model.domain.Compromisso;
import model.domain.Vendedor;
import model.service.ServiceLocator;
import org.jdesktop.observablecollections.ObservableCollections;

/**
 *
 * @author joao.rolim
 */
public final class CompromissoControl {
    private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private Compromisso compromissoDigitado;
    private Compromisso compromissoSelecionado;
    private List<Vendedor> vendedorTabela;
    private List<Cliente> clienteTable;
    private List<Compromisso> compromissoTabela;
    private final CompromissoDao compromissoDao;

    public CompromissoControl() {
        compromissoDao = ServiceLocator.getCompromissoDao();
        compromissoTabela = ObservableCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<Compromisso>());

        clienteTable = ObservableCollections.observableList(
                new ArrayList<Cliente>());
        clienteTable.addAll(compromissoDao.buscarClientes());

        vendedorTabela = ObservableCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<Vendedor>());
        vendedorTabela.addAll(compromissoDao.buscarVendedores());        
        novo();
        pesquisar();
    }

    public Compromisso getCompromissoDigitado() {
        return compromissoDigitado;
    }

    public void setCompromissoDigitado(Compromisso compromissoDigitado) {
        Compromisso oldcompromissoDigitado = this.compromissoDigitado;
        this.compromissoDigitado = compromissoDigitado;
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("compromissoDigitado",oldcompromissoDigitado,compromissoDigitado);
    }

    public Compromisso getCompromissoSelecionado() {
        return compromissoSelecionado;
    }

    public void setCompromissoSelecionado(Compromisso compromissoSelecionado) {
        this.compromissoSelecionado = compromissoSelecionado;
        if (this.compromissoSelecionado != null) {
            setCompromissoDigitado(compromissoSelecionado);
        }

    }

    public List<Compromisso> getCompromissoTabela() {
        return compromissoTabela;
    }

    public void setCompromissoTabela(List<Compromisso> compromissoTabela) {
        this.compromissoTabela = compromissoTabela;
    }


    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener property){
       propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(property);
    }
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener property){
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(property);
    }

    public void novo() {
        setCompromissoDigitado(new Compromisso());
    }


    public void salvar(){
        compromissoDao.salvarAtualizar(compromissoDigitado);
    }

    public void excluir(){
        compromissoDao.exluir(compromissoSelecionado);
    }

    public void pesquisar() {
        compromissoTabela.clear();
        compromissoTabela.addAll(compromissoDao.pesquisaGeral(compromissoDigitado));
    }

    public List<Vendedor> getVendedorTabela() {
        return vendedorTabela;

    }

    public void setVendedorTabela(List<Vendedor> vendedorTabela) {
        //Vendedor vendedor = this.vendedorTabela.
        this.vendedorTabela = vendedorTabela;
    }


    public List<Cliente> getClienteTable() {
        return this.clienteTable;


    }

    public void setClienteTable(List<Cliente> clienteTable) {
        this.clienteTable = clienteTable;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simples de se resolver o problema da exibição do `JComboBox` é sobrescrevendo o método `toString()` das suas duas classes Vendedor e Cliente, retornando o que você quer que seja exibido. Pelo que vi nos códigos, você pode fazer assim para as duas classes:

```
public String toString(){
    return this.nome;
}
```

Desta forma, os `JCombobox` irão exibir o nome do vendedor e o nome do Cliente. Outra forma é [criando seu próprio ComboModel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105753/28595), mas ai você teria que criar um para cada combo.

Comment: Puxa era só isso mesmo que faltava, cara como pude esquecer do toString() valeu!