# Atualizar ComboBox que recebe uma lista de outro painel

Tags: java, swing

Tenho uma tela onde cadastro um filme, e jogo para um `ArrayList` com uma classe Filme, que contém alguns atributos como titulo, ano, nada de mais até ai.

Então eu quero que na minha outra tela onde eu tenho um comboBox chamado "Selecione o filme", seja possível selecionar todos filmes cadastrados, mas o que acontece é que esse comboBox não atualiza, como ele vem setado ao iniciar o programa ele fica.

Vi algumas coisas em fóruns sobre os métodos "revalidate()" e "replace", mas não funcionou.

Na questão da table é a mesma coisa, listar filmes adicionados em outra tela.

Segue o código completo com as funcionalidades básicas para testar:

Tela = windows application

```
package tela;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

public class Exemplo {

private JFrame frmHappyCine;
private JPanel t2_menuInicial;
private JPanel t4_realizarVendas;
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unused" })
private JComboBox comboBox;
private JButton btnVoltarMenu;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Exemplo window = new Exemplo();
                window.frmHappyCine.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Exemplo() {
    initialize();
}

String pass = "Palmeirense";
String name = "Tiago Saldanha";
private JComboBox comboBoxSelecionarFilme;
private JButton btnVendas;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JPanel t5_cadastroFilme;
private JTextField textNomeFilme;
private JTextPane textFieldDescricao;
private JTextField textFieldAno;
private JComboBox comboFaixaEtaria;
private JTextPane textFieldAtores;
private JTextField textFieldDuracao;

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private void initialize() { 

    Filme filme = new Filme();

    ArrayList<Filme> filmeArray = new ArrayList<Filme>();


    frmHappyCine = new JFrame();
    frmHappyCine.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    frmHappyCine.setTitle("Happy Cine");
    frmHappyCine.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    frmHappyCine.setBounds(350, 100, 700, 600);
    frmHappyCine.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmHappyCine.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

    t2_menuInicial = new JPanel();
    frmHappyCine.getContentPane().add(t2_menuInicial, "name_813525675668965");
    t2_menuInicial.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblmenuInicial = new JLabel("Menu inicial");
    lblmenuInicial.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    lblmenuInicial.setBounds(288, 146, 108, 14);
    t2_menuInicial.add(lblmenuInicial);

    btnVendas = new JButton("Realizar Vendas");
    btnVendas.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            t2_menuInicial.setVisible(false);
            t4_realizarVendas.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnVendas.setBounds(235, 199, 213, 23);
    t2_menuInicial.add(btnVendas);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Cadastrar Filme");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            t2_menuInicial.setVisible(false);
            t5_cadastroFilme.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(235, 243, 213, 23);
    t2_menuInicial.add(btnNewButton);

    t4_realizarVendas = new JPanel();
    t4_realizarVendas.repaint();
    frmHappyCine.getContentPane().add(t4_realizarVendas, "name_1417798624613276");
    t4_realizarVendas.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblVendas = new JLabel("Venda de Ingressos");
    lblVendas.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    lblVendas.setBounds(259, 11, 165, 23);
    t4_realizarVendas.add(lblVendas);

    JLabel lblTituloDoFilme = new JLabel("T\u00EDtulo do Filme");
    lblTituloDoFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    lblTituloDoFilme.setBounds(21, 105, 159, 23);
    t4_realizarVendas.add(lblTituloDoFilme);

    btnVoltarMenu = new JButton("Voltar");
    btnVoltarMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            t4_realizarVendas.setVisible(false);
            t2_menuInicial.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnVoltarMenu.setForeground(Color.RED);
    btnVoltarMenu.setBounds(585, 527, 89, 23);
    t4_realizarVendas.add(btnVoltarMenu);

    comboBoxSelecionarFilme = new JComboBox();
    comboBoxSelecionarFilme.setToolTipText("Selecione o filme");
    comboBoxSelecionarFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));


    String[] stringFilme = new String[filmeArray.size()];
    filmeArray.toArray(stringFilme);
    for (int i = 0; i < filmeArray.size(); i++) {
        stringFilme[i] = filmeArray.get(i).getTitulo();
        System.out.println(filmeArray.get(i).getTitulo());
    }

    comboBoxSelecionarFilme.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(stringFilme));
    comboBoxSelecionarFilme.setBounds(205, 105, 436, 23);
    t4_realizarVendas.add(comboBoxSelecionarFilme);

    t5_cadastroFilme = new JPanel();
    frmHappyCine.getContentPane().add(t5_cadastroFilme, "name_813525692590336");
    t5_cadastroFilme.setLayout(null);

    JLabel nomeMenuCadastro = new JLabel("Cadastro de Filme");
    nomeMenuCadastro.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    nomeMenuCadastro.setBounds(267, 11, 150, 23);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(nomeMenuCadastro);

    textNomeFilme = new JTextField();
    textNomeFilme.setBounds(48, 140, 319, 23);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(textNomeFilme);
    textNomeFilme.setColumns(10);

    JLabel nomeFilme = new JLabel("Titulo");
    nomeFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    nomeFilme.setBounds(48, 115, 319, 14);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(nomeFilme);

    JLabel generoFilme = new JLabel("Descri\u00E7\u00E3o");
    generoFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    generoFilme.setBounds(48, 174, 319, 14);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(generoFilme);

    JLabel anoFilme = new JLabel("Ano");
    anoFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    anoFilme.setBounds(413, 115, 86, 14);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(anoFilme);

    textFieldAno = new JTextField();
    textFieldAno.setColumns(10);
    textFieldAno.setBounds(413, 140, 86, 23);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(textFieldAno);

    JLabel ator_principalFilme = new JLabel("Atores Principais");
    ator_principalFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    ator_principalFilme.setBounds(48, 308, 319, 14);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(ator_principalFilme);


    JButton btnSalvarFilme = new JButton("Salvar");
    btnSalvarFilme.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String retorno = "";
            if (textNomeFilme.getText().equals(""))
            {
                retorno += "\n Informe um nome para o filme.";
            }
            if (textFieldAno.getText().equals(""))
            {
                retorno +=  "\n Informe um ano para o filme.";
            }
            if (textFieldDescricao.getText().equals(""))
            {
                retorno += "\n Informe uma descrição para o filme.";
            }
            if (textFieldAtores.getText().equals(""))
            {
                retorno += "\n Informe atores principais para o filme.";
            }
            if (textFieldDuracao.getText().equals(""))
            {
                retorno += "\n Informe uma duração em minutos para o filme.";
            }

            if (retorno != "")
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, retorno);
            }
            else
            {
                filme.setTitulo(textNomeFilme.getText());
                filme.setAno(textFieldAno.getText());
                filme.setDescricao(textFieldDescricao.getText());
                filme.setFaixaEtaria(comboFaixaEtaria.getSelectedItem().toString());
                filme.setAtoresPrincipais(textFieldAtores.getText());

                try{
                    filme.setDuracaoMinutos(Double.parseDouble(textFieldDuracao.getText()));
                }catch(Exception descricao){
                    String msg = "A duração em minutos do filme não pode conter letras ou caracters especiais!"; 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnSalvarFilme, msg);
                }

                filmeArray.add(filme);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme salvo com sucesso!");
                textNomeFilme.setText(null);
                textFieldAno.setText(null);
                textFieldDescricao.setText(null);
                textFieldAtores.setText(null);
                textFieldDuracao.setText(null);
            }
        }
    });

    btnSalvarFilme.setForeground(new Color(0, 102, 0));
    btnSalvarFilme.setBounds(585, 11, 89, 23);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(btnSalvarFilme);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Para cadastrar atores insira uma v\u00EDrgula entre cada nome.");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblNewLabel.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(48, 398, 369, 14);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblFaixa = new JLabel("Faixa et\u00E1ria");
    lblFaixa.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    lblFaixa.setBounds(413, 176, 86, 14);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(lblFaixa);

    JLabel lblDuraoEmMinutos = new JLabel("Dura\u00E7\u00E3o em minutos");
    lblDuraoEmMinutos.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    lblDuraoEmMinutos.setBounds(413, 304, 143, 23);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(lblDuraoEmMinutos);

    textFieldDuracao = new JTextField();
    textFieldDuracao.setColumns(10);
    textFieldDuracao.setBounds(413, 333, 86, 23);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(textFieldDuracao);

    JButton btnVoltar_1 = new JButton("Voltar");
    btnVoltar_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            t5_cadastroFilme.setVisible(false);
            t2_menuInicial.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnVoltar_1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    btnVoltar_1.setBounds(585, 527, 89, 23);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(btnVoltar_1);

    textFieldDescricao = new JTextPane();
    textFieldDescricao.setBounds(48, 199, 319, 98);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(textFieldDescricao);

    textFieldAtores = new JTextPane();
    textFieldAtores.setBounds(48, 333, 319, 54);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(textFieldAtores);

    comboFaixaEtaria = new JComboBox();
    comboFaixaEtaria.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Selecione", "12", "14", "16", "18"}));
    comboFaixaEtaria.setSelectedIndex(0);
    comboFaixaEtaria.setBounds(413, 202, 86, 20);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(comboFaixaEtaria);

    JComboBox comboBoxFaixa = new JComboBox();
    comboBoxFaixa.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Selecione", "Livre", "12 Anos", "14 Anos", "16 Anos", "18 Anos"}));
    comboBoxFaixa.setSelectedIndex(0);
    comboBoxFaixa.setBounds(413, 201, 86, 20);
    t5_cadastroFilme.add(comboBoxFaixa);

    }
}
```

Classe Filme:

```
package tela;

public class Filme {

private String titulo;
private String ano;
private String descricao;
private String faixaEtaria;
private String atoresPrincipais;
private double duracaoMinutos;


public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}
public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}
public String getAno() {
    return ano;
}
public void setAno(String ano) {
    this.ano = ano;
}
public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}
public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}
public String getFaixaEtaria() {
    return faixaEtaria;
}
public void setFaixaEtaria(String faixaEtaria) {
    this.faixaEtaria = faixaEtaria;
}
public String getAtoresPrincipais() {
    return atoresPrincipais;
}
public void setAtoresPrincipais(String atoresPrincipais) {
    this.atoresPrincipais = atoresPrincipais;
}
public double getDuracaoMinutos() {
    return duracaoMinutos;
}
public void setDuracaoMinutos(double duracaoMinutos) {
    this.duracaoMinutos = duracaoMinutos;
}


}
```

Comment: Bem vinda ao SOPT. Por favor, adicione um **[mcve]** do seu código, para que seja possivel testar e reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Pelo que estou vendo, é bem provavel que você precisará criar um `ComboBoxModel` para o objeto Filme. [**Neste link**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105753/28595) há um exemplo muito parecido com o seu.

Comment: @diegofm Alterado, estou olhando o exemplo que você indicou, valeu :)

Comment: Sugiro que, até para questões de organização, você separe estes paineis em classes separadas. Isso facilita a manutenção do código. O fato de você ter feito tudo dentro de apenas um método é o grande causador do problema. A tela é toda carregada na abertura, de modo que não adianta adicionar filme mais, pois o combo da outra tela já foi carregado com a lista vazia.

Comment: Vou refazer como você sugeriu então, valeu!

Comment: Outra dica, remova esse botao "voltar" dentro dos componentes. Ele vai funcionar melhor dentro do Frame principal, dai você controla a exibição dele quando o painel inicial estiver visivel ou nao.

Comment: Nunca fiz desse modo, mas vou dar uma pesquisada qualquer coisa, valeu pelas dicas. :)

Comment: Pode fechar o tópico, caso eu não conseguir, eu crio um novamente kkk

Comment: Não tem muito segredo, basta criar classes tipo `MenuInicialPainel`, `RealizarVendasPainel` e `CadastrarFilmePainel` e arrastar pra lá todos os componentes de cada painel e seus métodos. Outra alternativa é utilizar JInternalFrame, onde cada painel viraria um Frame interno dentro do JFrame, facilitaria bastante até controlar a visibilidade de cada um.

Comment: Até tentei separar os seus paineis em classes diferentes, mas como está muito extenso o numero de componentes, acabei não dando continuidade. A ideia é criar classes de cada tela extendendo de JPanel, vou tentar adaptar o seu código e mando aqui.

Comment: Se puder ajudar então através do chat agradeço!

Comment: Veja minha resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da forma como o código estava, seria complicado qualquer adaptação. Separei os paineis em classes diferentes e para resolver o problema do combo sem alterar a estrutura do seu código, implementei um *listener* no Painel onde o combo se encontrava, de forma que ele vai ser invocado sempre que o painel for configurado como visível(através do método `setVisible()`) e vai atualizar o model do combo com a lista novamente, devido a uma particularidade no [comportamento do `ArrayList`](http://www.javaprogressivo.net/2012/09/arrays-em-metodos-passagem-por-valor-e_16.html), ao ser passado como parâmetro da classe principal para as outras classes de painel.

O código ficou assim:

Classe Exemplo agora está mais limpa:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Exemplo {

    private JFrame frmHappyCine;
    private JPanel t2_menuInicial;
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unused"})

    String pass = "Palmeirense";
    String name = "Tiago Saldanha";
    private JComboBox comboBox;
    private JButton btnVendas;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    //transformei a lista em atributo para poder usá-la
    //como parametro dos paineis        
    private ArrayList<Filme> filmeArray = new ArrayList<>();
    //criei dois atributos para representar os paineis
    private CadastroFilmePainel filmePanel;
    private RealizarVendasPainel vendasPanel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Exemplo window = new Exemplo();
                    window.frmHappyCine.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Exemplo() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    private void initialize() {

        frmHappyCine = new JFrame();
        frmHappyCine.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        frmHappyCine.setTitle("Happy Cine");
        frmHappyCine.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        frmHappyCine.setBounds(350, 100, 700, 600);
        frmHappyCine.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmHappyCine.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        t2_menuInicial = new JPanel();
        frmHappyCine.getContentPane().add(t2_menuInicial, "name_813525675668965");
        t2_menuInicial.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblmenuInicial = new JLabel("Menu inicial");
        lblmenuInicial.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblmenuInicial.setBounds(288, 146, 108, 14);
        t2_menuInicial.add(lblmenuInicial);

        btnVendas = new JButton("Realizar Vendas");
        btnVendas.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                t2_menuInicial.setVisible(false);
                //vendasPanel é uma instancia do painel de realizar vendas
                vendasPanel.revalidate();
                vendasPanel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnVendas.setBounds(235, 199, 213, 23);
        t2_menuInicial.add(btnVendas);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Cadastrar Filme");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                t2_menuInicial.setVisible(false);
                //filmePanel é uma instancia do painel de cadastrar filmes
                filmePanel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(235, 243, 213, 23);
        t2_menuInicial.add(btnNewButton);
        //adiciona o painel de vendas a tela principal
        vendasPanel = new RealizarVendasPainel(filmeArray);
        frmHappyCine.getContentPane().add(vendasPanel, "name_1417798624613276");
        //adiciona o painel de filmes a tela principal
        filmePanel = new CadastroFilmePainel(filmeArray);
        frmHappyCine.getContentPane().add(filmePanel, "name_813525692590336");

    }
}
```

Graças as separações que já havia mencionado nos comentários, agora temos duas novas classes para cada painel específico do programa:

**Painel RealizarVendas(onde se encontra o `JComboBox`):**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RealizarVendasPainel extends JPanel {

    private JButton btnVoltarMenu;
    private JComboBox comboBoxSelecionarFilme;
    ArrayList<Filme> filmeArray;

    public RealizarVendasPainel(ArrayList listaFilmes) {
        //recebe a lista de filmes da tela principal
        this.filmeArray = listaFilmes;
        initComponents();
        //adiciona um listener para monitorar 
        //quando o painel for setado como visivel
        //e atualizar o combo de filmes
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                super.componentShown(e);
                //atualiza o combo de filmes
                comboBoxSelecionarFilme.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(getListModel()));
            }

        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        this.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblVendas = new JLabel("Venda de Ingressos");
        lblVendas.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblVendas.setBounds(259, 11, 165, 23);
        this.add(lblVendas);

        JLabel lblTituloDoFilme = new JLabel("T\u00EDtulo do Filme");
        lblTituloDoFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblTituloDoFilme.setBounds(21, 105, 159, 23);
        this.add(lblTituloDoFilme);

        btnVoltarMenu = new JButton("Voltar");
        btnVoltarMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnVoltarMenu.setForeground(Color.RED);
        btnVoltarMenu.setBounds(585, 527, 89, 23);
        this.add(btnVoltarMenu);

        comboBoxSelecionarFilme = new JComboBox();
        comboBoxSelecionarFilme.setToolTipText("Selecione o filme");
        comboBoxSelecionarFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        comboBoxSelecionarFilme.setBounds(205, 105, 436, 23);
        comboBoxSelecionarFilme.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(getListModel()));
        this.add(comboBoxSelecionarFilme);
    }

    /**
     * Método que irá converter o arraylist de filmes
     * em um vetor de strings
     * 
     * @return vetor de strings com o nome dos filmes
     */
    private String[] getListModel() {
        String[] stringFilme = new String[filmeArray.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < filmeArray.size(); i++) {
            stringFilme[i] = filmeArray.get(i).getTitulo();
            System.out.println(filmeArray.get(i).getTitulo());
        }
        return stringFilme;
    }
}
```

**Painel de Cadastro de Filmes:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CadastroFilmePainel extends JPanel {

    private JTextField textNomeFilme;
    private JTextField textFieldAno;
    private JTextPane textFieldDescricao;
    private JTextPane textFieldAtores;
    private JTextField textFieldDuracao;
    private JComboBox comboFaixaEtaria;
    private Filme filme;
    ArrayList<Filme> filmeArray;

    public CadastroFilmePainel(ArrayList<Filme> listaFilmes) {
        //recebe a lista de filmes do Frame
        this.filmeArray = listaFilmes;
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        this.setLayout(null);

        JLabel nomeMenuCadastro = new JLabel("Cadastro de Filme");
        nomeMenuCadastro.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        nomeMenuCadastro.setBounds(267, 11, 150, 23);
        this.add(nomeMenuCadastro);

        textNomeFilme = new JTextField();
        textNomeFilme.setBounds(48, 140, 319, 23);
        this.add(textNomeFilme);
        textNomeFilme.setColumns(10);

        JLabel nomeFilme = new JLabel("Titulo");
        nomeFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        nomeFilme.setBounds(48, 115, 319, 14);
        this.add(nomeFilme);

        JLabel generoFilme = new JLabel("Descri\u00E7\u00E3o");
        generoFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        generoFilme.setBounds(48, 174, 319, 14);
        this.add(generoFilme);

        JLabel anoFilme = new JLabel("Ano");
        anoFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        anoFilme.setBounds(413, 115, 86, 14);
        this.add(anoFilme);

        textFieldAno = new JTextField();
        textFieldAno.setColumns(10);
        textFieldAno.setBounds(413, 140, 86, 23);
        this.add(textFieldAno);

        JLabel ator_principalFilme = new JLabel("Atores Principais");
        ator_principalFilme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        ator_principalFilme.setBounds(48, 308, 319, 14);
        this.add(ator_principalFilme);

        JButton btnSalvarFilme = new JButton("Salvar");
        btnSalvarFilme.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String retorno = "";
                if (textNomeFilme.getText().equals("")) {
                    retorno += "\n Informe um nome para o filme.";
                } else if (textFieldAno.getText().equals("")) {
                    retorno += "\n Informe um ano para o filme.";
                } else if (textFieldDescricao.getText().equals("")) {
                    retorno += "\n Informe uma descrição para o filme.";
                } else if (textFieldAtores.getText().equals("")) {
                    retorno += "\n Informe atores principais para o filme.";
                } else if (textFieldDuracao.getText().equals("")) {
                    retorno += "\n Informe uma duração em minutos para o filme.";
                }

                if (!"".equals(retorno)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, retorno);
                } else {
                    filme = new Filme();
                    filme.setTitulo(textNomeFilme.getText());
                    filme.setAno(textFieldAno.getText());
                    filme.setDescricao(textFieldDescricao.getText());
                    filme.setFaixaEtaria(comboFaixaEtaria.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    filme.setAtoresPrincipais(textFieldAtores.getText());

                    try {
                        filme.setDuracaoMinutos(Double.parseDouble(textFieldDuracao.getText()));
                    } catch (Exception descricao) {
                        String msg = "A duração em minutos do filme não pode conter letras ou caracters especiais!";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnSalvarFilme, msg);
                    }

                    filmeArray.add(filme);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme salvo com sucesso!");
                    textNomeFilme.setText(null);
                    textFieldAno.setText(null);
                    textFieldDescricao.setText(null);
                    textFieldAtores.setText(null);
                    textFieldDuracao.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

        btnSalvarFilme.setForeground(new Color(0, 102, 0));
        btnSalvarFilme.setBounds(585, 11, 89, 23);
        this.add(btnSalvarFilme);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Para cadastrar atores insira uma v\u00EDrgula entre cada nome.");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(48, 398, 369, 14);
        this.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblFaixa = new JLabel("Faixa et\u00E1ria");
        lblFaixa.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblFaixa.setBounds(413, 176, 86, 14);
        this.add(lblFaixa);

        JLabel lblDuraoEmMinutos = new JLabel("Dura\u00E7\u00E3o em minutos");
        lblDuraoEmMinutos.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblDuraoEmMinutos.setBounds(413, 304, 143, 23);
        this.add(lblDuraoEmMinutos);

        textFieldDuracao = new JTextField();
        textFieldDuracao.setColumns(10);
        textFieldDuracao.setBounds(413, 333, 86, 23);
        this.add(textFieldDuracao);

        JButton btnVoltar_1 = new JButton("Voltar");
        btnVoltar_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnVoltar_1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnVoltar_1.setBounds(585, 527, 89, 23);
        this.add(btnVoltar_1);

        textFieldDescricao = new JTextPane();
        textFieldDescricao.setBounds(48, 199, 319, 98);
        this.add(textFieldDescricao);

        textFieldAtores = new JTextPane();
        textFieldAtores.setBounds(48, 333, 319, 54);
        this.add(textFieldAtores);

        comboFaixaEtaria = new JComboBox();
        comboFaixaEtaria.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"Selecione", "12", "14", "16", "18"}));
        comboFaixaEtaria.setSelectedIndex(0);
        comboFaixaEtaria.setBounds(413, 202, 86, 20);
        this.add(comboFaixaEtaria);

        JComboBox comboBoxFaixa = new JComboBox();
        comboBoxFaixa.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"Selecione", "Livre", "12 Anos", "14 Anos", "16 Anos", "18 Anos"}));
        comboBoxFaixa.setSelectedIndex(0);
        comboBoxFaixa.setBounds(413, 201, 86, 20);
        this.add(comboBoxFaixa);

    }

}
```

O resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Não tinha notado um leve probleminha com o combo de idade, que permanece o ultimo valor selecionado no cadastro anterior. Caso queira arrumar esse comportamento, basta adicionar `comboFaixaEtaria.setSelectedIndex(0);` no final do `actionPerformed` do botão de salvar filme, pois tendo em vista que a lista inicia com um tooltip *"Selecione"*, o "reset" desse componente poderia ser simplesmente definir o primeiro item como selecionado.

```
textNomeFilme.setText(null);
textFieldAno.setText(null);
textFieldDescricao.setText(null);
textFieldAtores.setText(null);
textFieldDuracao.setText(null);
comboFaixaEtaria.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Comment: Bah, vlw Diego
Vou usar seu exemplo para dividir todas as telas.  E o combo box também. Ajudou muito mesmo :D

Comment: @KimberlyGonçalves disponha! :)

Comment: Só uma ultima pergunta, se eu precisar de uma terceira tela, que abre através da segunda, como faço?
Pois só a primeira tela que tem o Frame definido.
Tentei colocar o 
frmHappyCine.getContentPane().add(tela3, "name_1417798624613276"); na tela 1
mas não funcionou, estou a horas nisso, você já ajudou até demais, muito obrigada mesmo.

Comment: @KimberlyGonçalves Seria interessante abrir outra pergunta, pois se trata de uma nova duvida, até para evitar que esta resposta  fique extensa demais e saia do escopo desta pergunta. Ao criar, não esqueça de citar esta pergunta, para facilitar outras pessoas tentarem ajudar tambem :)

Answer (score -1):

No comboBox, a linha que você precisa dar atenção é a seguinte:

```
comboBoxSelecionarFilme.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(stringFilme));
```

Nela você passa a string com os filmes para o comboBox e só faz isso uma vez. Se você precisa que essa lista se atualize, você precisa atualizar o stringFilme e carregar o comboBox **novamente** com stringFilme atualizado. Recomendo que crie uma função que agrupe todas essas operações:

1- recarregar uma lista atualizada com o filmeArray;

2- recarregar o stringFilme a partir do filmeArray;

3- recarregar o comboBoxSelecionarFilme. Nesse caso é só copiar a linha citada acima.

Aí é só usar a cada alteração.

Comment: Sinceramente isso não resolve o problema, não da forma que foi explicado. Veja [meu comentario](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169516/atualizar-combobox-e-jtable/169529#comment349180_169516) a respeito do que está causando o problema. A solução é mais complexa que isso, eu só não respondi porque teria que alterar outras coisas, o que desviaria a resposta do real problema.