# Popular JComboBox com Strings e IDs trazidos do banco de dados

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Preciso popular uma `JComboBox` com os dados trazidos de uma tabela do meu Banco de Dados MySQL, porém não sei como deixar um item atrelado ao ID correspondente.

Exemplo: o ID 1 se refere ao perfil ADM e o ID 2 se refere ao perfil Padrão. Se o usuário selecionar o item ADM, o ID 1 deve ser inserido no BD.

Existe algum método ou propriedade que guarde o ID sem necessariamente mostrá-lo na JComboBox?

```
public void fillCB(){
    try{
        ResultSet rs;
        perfil.select();//esse método busca no BD os perfis existentes
        rs=perfil.getRs();//aqui eu pego o ResultSet existente na minha classe perfil
        while(rs.next()){
            cbPerfil.addItem(rs.getString("nome"));//e aqui populo a minha ComboBox com a descrição do perfil, porém preciso trazer o ID para relacionar com o item
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException erro){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro!\n"+erro);
    }
}
```

Acima o código do método para preencher a ComboBox.

Comment: É uma tabela com 2 campos? Se sim, vou lhe dar uma dica, crie um comboboxmodel. Muito mais facil, deixa seu código organizado e de fácil manutenção.

Comment: Sim, apenas 2 campos. Teria algum exemplo de uso?

Comment: Tô no celular agora, mas olha esse exemplo dessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105753/28595

Comment: Li o exemplo e vi que citam DAO, porém o meu projeto não possui essa implementação. Preciso implementar o DAO ou há alguma outra forma?

Comment: Pra facilitar, adicione um [mcve] para que seja possível executar seu código. Assim fica mais fácil pensar em uma solucao que te atenda.

Comment: @diegofm editei o post com o código do meu método

Comment: A resposta lhe ajudou? Se sim, você pode marcá-la como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda da resposta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que a opção mais recomendada neste caso é utilizar uma versão personalizada de um [`ComboBoxModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html). Só que para isso, você também precisa criar uma representação [**POJO**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Objects) dessa tabela `Perfil`, algo mais ou menos assim:

```
public class Perfil {

    private int id;
    private String nome;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.nome;
    }
}
```

O método `toString()` que sobrescrevi(como foi feito [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105753/28595)) é para que seja exibido o nome do perfil como representação do objeto no combo.

Como eu disse nos comentários, o ideal é separar responsabilidades e criar uma classe que interaja com o banco de dados a parte, e não delegar isto a classe que constrói a tela, mas como não foi apresentado mais nenhum detalhe da tela, vou me basear no método da pergunta. Você deve resgatar os dados da sua tabela e atribuir a classe acima, criando uma lista de todos os itens do banco:

```
List<Perfil> lista = new ArrayList<>();

ResultSet rs;
perfil.select();//esse método busca no BD os perfis existentes
rs=perfil.getRs();//aqui eu pego o ResultSet existente na minha classe perfil
while(rs.next()){
    Perfil p  = new Perfil();
    p.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    p.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
    lista.add(p);
}
```

Tendo uma lista de objetos `Perfil` definida, você pode utilizar esta classe que elaborei há algum tempo, que pode ser utilizada como um `ComboBoxmodel` genérico para qualquer tipo de objeto recebido:

```
public class GenericComboModel<E> extends AbstractListModel<E> implements ComboBoxModel<E>{

    private List<E> itemList;
    private E selection;

    public GenericComboModel(List<E> list) {
        this.itemList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public E getElementAt(int index) {
        return this.itemList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        return this.selection;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
        this.selection = (E) anItem;
    }
}
```

Para usar, após popular a lista, é só configurar a classe acima como model do combo, passando a lista e parametrizando o objeto que a classe tratará na lista:

```
cbPerfil.setModel(new GenericComboModel<Perfil>(lista));
```

Para resgatar a opção selecionada em algum momento do código:

```
Perfil pSelected = (Perfil)cbPerfil.getSelectedItem();
```

Isto resgatará um `Perfil`, e para pegar o id basta chamar `pSelected.getId()`.