# Pegar Id de um objetos no combobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Em um Frame para cadastro de carros, tenho um combobox1 com as marcas de carros e outro combobox2 com os modelos, quando escolho uma marca no CB1 só aparecem no CB2 os modelos relacionados aquela marca.
Marcas  e modelos são tabelas do banco, que são usadas por uma tabela Carros

```
 MARCAS
    idMarca
    nome

 MODELOS
    idModelo
    idMarca
    nome

CARROS
    idCarro
    placa
    idMarca
    idmodelo
```

Consigo popular os dois CB's de forma correta buscando os dados do banco e passando para ArrayList's

```
public void preencherMarcas(){
   MarcasControle marcasControle = new MarcasControle();
   jComboBox1.removeAllItems();

    ArrayList<MarcasModelo> vetorMarcas = new ArrayList();  
    vetorMarcas = marcasControle.preencherMarcas();
    for (MarcasModelo marcas : vetorMarcas) {
         jComboBox1.addItem(marcas.getNome());
         }  
    }

    public void preencherModelos(){
    ModelosControle modelosControle = new ModelosControle();
    jComboBox2.removeAllItems();  
    ArrayList<ModelosModelo> vetorModelos = new ArrayList();  
    vetorModelos = modelosControle.preencherModelos(id);
        for (ModelosModelo modelos : vetorModelos) {
           jComboBox2.addItem(modelos.getNome());
        } 
     }
```

Porem para persistir os dados eu preciso saber o IdMarca item selecionado no combobox1 e o idModelo do item selecionado do combobox2.
Ai que ta o meu problema, não esto conseguindo fechar esse raciocínio de como fazer isso.
De como pegar essas informações(idMarca e idModelo) dos combombox's.
Tentei da forma abaixo, mas não funcionou, apresentou o erro

```
Marcas mm = (Marcas)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
int idMarcas = m.getId();
```

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to modelo.Marcas

Comment: Se você está populando seu combobox com strings, ao pegar o selecionado ele também será uma string. O que você deve fazer é, ou popular o combobox com os próprios objetos e manter o content de cada item com a descrição do item como você já tem agora, ou por meio da string selecionada, ir na lista de objetos e  filtrar por essa descrição selecionada

Answer (score 2):

O erro ocorre porque você está populando o combobox com um conjunto de strings e não com o objetos do tipo `Marcas`, como pode ser visto no seu próprio código:

```
ArrayList<MarcasModelo> vetorMarcas = new ArrayList();  
vetorMarcas = marcasControle.preencherMarcas();
for (MarcasModelo marcas : vetorMarcas) {
     jComboBox1.addItem(marcas.getNome());
     }  
}
```

Não há como fazer cast de String para seu objeto, o java não sabe fazer isso. Ou você define o comb para receber somente objetos do tipo `Marcas`(o que provavelmente irá até dispensar o cast) ou altera a forma como está tratando o item selecionado, como uma string e sem cast e formule outro jeito de poder pesquisar o id da marca selecionada no combobox.

Caso opte por popular o combobox com seu objeto, nos links abaixo ha soluções que explicam algumas formas de se fazer isso.

- [Popular JComboBox com Strings e IDs trazidos do banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204073/28595)
- [Preencher JComboBox com um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105695/28595)