# Preencher JTextField à partir de jComboBox

Tags: java, txt, combobox, jtextfield

Tenho um arquivo .txt com strings assim:

```
luis;123;456;789;11/11/1111
```

A primeira parte do meu problema era popular o `jComboBox` apenas com o primeiro valor (nome), consegui fazer até que de boa, mas agora preciso que um `jTextField` se altere para o terceiro valor conforme eu alterno a seleção no `jComboBox`.
Segue abaixo como populei o combobox, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer para o textfield ser preenchido conforme alterna a seleção do combobox.

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<String> ComboClientes;

public void popularCombo() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        ComboClientes = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
           String clientes = "";
           FileReader fr;
           fr = new FileReader("clientes.txt");
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
           while ((clientes = br.readLine())!=null){                        
                String quebra [] = clientes.split(";");
                String nome = quebra[0];  
                ComboClientes.addElement(nome);                    
            }
           br.close();
           fr.close();
           jComboBoxCliente.setModel(ComboClientes);
        }
```

Comment: Eu não estou vendo o `jTextField` a ser preenchido.

Comment: É tudo feito em um jFrame, não editei nada do código do jTextField ainda pois não sei o que fazer para que ele set o texto conforme o combobox é selecionado.

Comment: Seu código não está completo o suficiente para entendermos o problema, porém, percebo que a abordagem que está seguindo pode não ser a ideal para o que pretende. Se você tem uma base de dados(seu txt é sua base de dados) e precisa manipular ela em multiplas partes dentro do código, o ideal é que você modele esses dados, de modo a se trabalhar melhor com eles no código. Ficar dando split aqui e ali você vai "sujar" seu código e a manutenção se tornará difícil até mesmo para você no futuro.

Comment: Veja um exemplo [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204149/164151) de como você deveria seguir na modelagem